how to use condition in ingress template in kubernetes
I have following Values.yaml file
ingress: {backendServiceName: serv-swarm-lc001, cluster_issuer: letsencrypt-oe-dev-001,
  ingressClassName: nginx-lc001, tls_acme: 'true'}
route:
  hosts:
    abcM:
      active: false
      host: chair112.abc.com
      logicalclustername: lc001
      offboardtimestamp: null
      physicalclustername: oe-dev-001
      region: us-east-1
      status: Triggered
      timestamp: |-
        {
          "timestamp": "2024-02-05T14:43:18.00847359Z"
        }
    SDzWAgVebH:
      active: true
      host: bis311.abc.com
      logicalclustername: lc001
      offboardtimestamp: NA
      physicalclustername: oe-dev-001
      region: us-east-1
      status: triggered
      timestamp: |-
        {
          "timestamp": "2024-04-04T15:54:21.649644213Z"
        }

below is the template for ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: {{ .Values.ingress.cluster_issuer }}
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: {{ .Values.ingress.tls_acme | quote }}
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: 16m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 16m
  name: ingress-{{ .Release.Name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels:
{{ include "common.labels" . | indent 4 }}
spec:
  ingressClassName: {{ .Values.ingress.ingressClassName }}
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.route.hosts }}
  - host: {{ - if .Values.route.hosts.host.active }} {{- end }}
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: {{ $.Values.ingress.backendServiceName }}
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: swaggerservice
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /swagger
        pathType: Prefix
  {{- end }}
  tls:
  {{- range .Values.route.hosts }}
  - hosts:
    - {{ .host | quote }}
    secretName: commodo-tls5
  {{- end }}

what we need is , we would like to process/add only those host entries which active true as value . if false , then host should not be added into ingress.
have added condition in ingress, line : 17, however, it is not working . getting error on parsing.
please suggest how we can add condition .
update 1
here is the updated ingress yaml file
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: {{ .Values.ingress.cluster_issuer }}
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: {{ .Values.ingress.tls_acme | quote }}
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: 16m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 16m
  name: ingress-{{ .Release.Name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels:
{{ include "common.labels" . | indent 4 }}
spec:
  ingressClassName: {{ .Values.ingress.ingressClassName }}
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.route.hosts }}{{ if .active }}
  - host: {{ .host | quote }}
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: {{ $.Values.ingress.backendServiceName }}
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: swaggerservice
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /swagger
        pathType: Prefix
      {{ end }}
  {{- end }}
  tls:
  {{- range .Values.route.hosts }} {{ if .active }}
  - hosts:
    - {{ .host | quote }}
    secretName: commodo-tls5
      {{ end }}
  {{- end }}


Instead of:
{{- range .Values.route.hosts }}
- host: {{ - if .Values.route.hosts.host.active }} {{- end }}
http:
  paths:
  - backend:
      service:
        name: {{ $.Values.ingress.backendServiceName }}
        port:
          number: 80
    path: /
    pathType: Prefix
  - backend:
      service:
        name: swaggerservice
        port:
          number: 80
    path: /swagger
    pathType: Prefix
{{- end }}

Try:
{{- range .Values.route.hosts }}{{ if .active }}
- host: {{ .host }}
  http:
    paths:
    - backend:
        service:
          name: {{ $.Values.ingress.backendServiceName }}
          port:
            number: 80
      path: /
      pathType: Prefix
    - backend:
        service:
          name: swaggerservice
          port:
            number: 80
      path: /swagger
      pathType: Prefix
  {{ end }}
{{- end }}

You might need to use a similar condition at the bottom as well:
- hosts:
  - {{ .host | quote }}
  secretName: commodo-tls5


I have update the ingress yaml file as you suggested, however, it is still adding the host entry whose active value is false . Please suggest

@user2315104 running helm template with the values file you provided there is only one host entry - I don't understand where is the problem. Please edit your question with the command you're trying to run, and what is the current output.
